# How to get SecureRandom to output 7 digit value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unique-key

```
SecureRandom.hex(n)
```

Seems to output a value of length 2n.

I'd like an output value of 7 (e.g., XSE7ENX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for 4 hex bytes and grab the first 7 characters

```
SecureRandom.hex(4).slice(0,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler syntax:

```
SecureRandom.hex.first(7)
```